# iOS Gitlab Ci Job failed

Tags: ios, gitlab, continuous-integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCxyT.png)

this is yml,how to fix this bug?

```
    image: ruby:3.0

before_script:
 - echo "berfore script" 
after_script:
 - echo "after script"

stages:
  - build

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - xcodebuild clean -project TestCiProject.xcodeproj -scheme TestCiProject | xcpretty
    - xcodebuild test -project TestCiProject.xcodeproj -scheme TestCiProject -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=15.0' | xcpretty -s
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add variables for the BASH command

PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"